# Tastcafe Studio is not able to record testcase step

Tags: javascript, testcafe, automation-testing

Hi I am trying to record automatic testing testcase using testcafe studio,
But the testcafe is not able to record the date selection from calendar popup date selection.

Here is the calendar Image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lwaf.png

Here is the inspect of the element of the calendar: `<input type="date" name="divisionName" required="" value="">`

**Please tell me how to give a date to the calendar, by using any teststudio feature? or any other way?**

Answer (score 0):

With TestCafe, you can only click on the custom date popup. TestCafe is the driver of TestCafe Studio, so TestCafe Studio can only record the click on the custom date popup. If you don't have a custom date popup, you can only set the date in this type of `input`. For example:

```js
await t.typeText(datetime, '2017-12-23')
```

Comment: Yes the testcafe studio is not able to record the date selection. while running the test it is not able to open the calendar pop-up resulting in date not selected.
And where to write the above code? ```await t.typeText(datetime, '2017-11-03T05:00')``` in define function feature?

Comment: You should add a [custom script](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401265/test-actions/custom-scripts), where you can call this action.